# Changing the color of a row based on a cell in another column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In my `A` column, I list number codes that represent tests I'm performing. Every few rows, I leave a cell empty, and color the row gray, to represent a divide in tests.

There are quite a lot of empty cells that I would would prefer to be a light gray instead of just white, to indicate they were intentionally left blank. These cells represent the result of a certain test case; though, not all test cases have actual results. While it is an option to hand fill every one of these cells with the color I want, I know Sheets has conditional formation functionality.

Here is an example picture illustrating what I mean:
[image: Test Sheet]

My question is: how do I use condition formatting to color the rows in columns E - G, without overwriting the darker gray lines I use to divide up the sheet? And is there any way I can have it automatically set the division rows as dark gray, as well as setting the Results and Pass/Fail cells as a light gray?

Answer (score 0):

A few rules is all that's needed. You mentioned formatting column G, but didn't provide any examples of it, so I've included it in this formulas all the same.

Conditional Formatting rules are applied in a "short-circuiting" order - the first one that is true is applied, and then no more are checked, starting with the rule at the top of the list.

1. Background format. `=ISBLANK($A1)` Applied to all columns that should get this row-based coloration. If A1 is empty, this row is empty.
   The `$` is used so that the same column is referenced across the whole range, otherwise when computing the format for column B, the reference `A1` would be translated to `B1`.
2. No result expected. `=ISBLANK($E1)` Applied to columns E:G. Is true if nothing is written in col E, but something is in col A.
3. Test Passed. Applied to column F. Self explanatory
4. Test Failed. Applied to column F. Self explanatory

[image: Rules Result]